# Maximum sum of strictly increasing susequence of size 4

Tags: c++, arrays, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Is there any more efficient way to get the maximum sum of strictly increasing subsequence of size 4?

I have used DP where `DP[i][j] = max(DP[k][j-1])` such that `k < i` and `A[k] < A[i], j < 4`, `A` is the array.
This solution has a time complexity of n^2.

I want to reduce the time complexity.

Let the array be 1, 10, 6, 8, 9, 11, 9, 9, 13
then the answer is 13 + 11 + 9 + 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `i` from 1 to 4, keep by descending maximum and sum, the best options that you have found already.  (You can use a skiplist, binary tree, or whatever for this.) This will be kept strictly descending by both maximum AND sum.

Then your update logic looks like this:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    for j in your array:
        find for i-1 the best candidate whose max is < j:
        if found:
            create new candidate by adding j to that one
            look for best candidate of size i with max smaller than or equal to this
            if not found or its sum is < this one:
                insert new candidate into data structure
                delete from data structure any existing elements whose max >= this and whose sum is <= this.
```

Every lookup is `O(log(n))`.  Inserts and deletes are also.  For each `i`, for each element, we do up to 2 lookups, 1 insert, and at some later point might do a delete.  For time `O(k n log(n))` where k is the length of increasing chain you're looking for.  (In your case, 4.)

Comment: I was not able to understand the approach. Please elaborate.

Comment: What's max here?

Comment: @DwaipayanBarman The max is the maximum of the ascending sequence.  The sum is the sum of the ascending sequence.  The key insight is that if at any point there are two sequences where A has a max >= B's, and a sum <= B's, then you can replace B with A in the final sequence and not do worse.

Comment: So the whole point is "throw away sequences that cannot be on their way to being optimal ASAP, keep the ones that possibly might lead to optimal in an easily searched sorted data structure".

Comment: Thanks, got it now.